# "very nearly gotten the guy to confess"

Tags: causatives

*He’s discovered a new suspect, and this new suspect has just enough evidence against him to suggest that, hey, maybe he killed Andrea instead of Naz. Box has even tracked this new suspect down and **very nearly gotten the guy to confess**, in a superbly creepy scene.*

Source: http://www.vox.com/2016/8/29/12688534/the-night-of-finale-recap-the-call-of-the-wild-verdict

I am not sure whether the part in bold is the causative as in the sentence like this: Wait, I'll get someone to help you! Or is the meaning simply that Box very nearly achieved to get a confession from the guy?

Comment: has ...(very nearly) ... gotten the guy to confess.  He got him to confess = he managed somehow to obtain a confession from him / he elicited a confession from him by some method of interrogation.

Comment: @TRomano - I read that as he *almost* got the guy to confess (he got near), but didn't. I've always wondered about these phrases, such as "the baseball nearly hit him.", Does that not mean that he was almost hit? It means he was hit, but barely?

Comment: @Bruce Wayne: yes, in the original it's almost (very nearly). I was explaining what "got him to confess" would mean.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

from my understanding it seems that the subject, Box, does not make the man confess, however the man almost does confess, or become very close to confessing. the easier way to imagine this is a running race. Pretend as if the man very nearly gotten to the finish. from this understanding we can see that the person running the race never finishes.

Comment: -1 for using nonstandard capitalization.